# Should `nullptr_t` be part of the global namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I see that Microsoft's `stddef.h` defines `nullptr_t` thus:

```
namespace std
{
    typedef decltype(__nullptr) nullptr_t;
}

using ::std::nullptr_t;
```

The *`using` decleration* injects `nullptr_t` into the global namespace. I can't find anything in the standard that says that this should be done.

<strike>I also see that in GCC `nullptr_t` isn't in the global namespace.</strike>

Can both implementations be allowed or is one of them a bug?
 *My bad, GCC behaves the same as CL*.

---

**Edit:** The same happens with `cstddef`, the following compiles fine with VC ([online too](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)).

```
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    nullptr_t nil = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference betweeen `using ::std::nullptr_t;` and `using std::nullptr_t;`? Nice question btw.

Comment: @gsamaras I don't think there's a difference.

Comment: There's no difference in this context. There is a difference if you have `namespace foo { namespace std { using nullptr_t = int } using std::nullptr_t; }`.

Comment: GCC does define it in the global namespace: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ginclude/stddef.h;hb=HEAD#l436

Comment: @JonathanWakely, oops, you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It must be in the global namespace.

> **D.5 C standard library headers [depr.c.headers]**
>
> 2 Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope. [...]

There is no exception here for names that are specific to C++. If C++ adds a name to `<cstddef>` that C's `<stddef.h>` doesn't provide, then C++'s `<stddef.h>` still needs to provide it too.

Comment: It's also injected into the global namespace for `<cstddef>`.

Comment: @Motti Yes, that's allowed. The `<cxxx>` headers must define names in the `std` namespace, and may also define them in the global namespace. The `<xxx.h>` headers must define them in the global namespace, and may also define them in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> I also see that in GCC nullptr_t isn't in the global namespace.

Are you sure about that?

https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ginclude/stddef.h;hb=HEAD#l436

You might have an older version of GCC, I see it there for GCC 4.8.0 and later.

> The same happens with cstddef,

That's not guaranteed to work. To use `::nullptr_t` portably you must include `<stddef.h>`. To use `std::nullptr_t` portably you must include `<cstddef>`.